# Returning 2d array from void function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, 2d

I have a function that looks like this:

```
void swapRows(int row_1, int row_2, double **matrix, int n, int m)
{
   double arrTemp = (double *)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
   int i;   

   for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
   {
      arrTemp[i] = matrix[row_1][i];
      *matrix[row_1][i] = matrix[row_2][i];
   }

   for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
   {
    *matrix[row_2][i] = arrTemp[i];
   }

}
```

I tried dereferencing the array using two stars and a single star but can not figure it out. I don't want to store it in another array and return it VIA a double function, I need to return it from this void function. I am just swapping rows in the array and need to return the modified array to the main function.

Comment: Unless I'm missing the point of this function it should have no memory allocations at all. You're swapping *rows*, and in this case that means two pointers to two rows simply need to be swapped. Bulk memory copying is unneeded.

Comment: @Kheldar because of your edit reason: No, that won´t run at all.

Comment: @deviantfan my view is that modifying the code in the question is a bad idea, because it transforms answers to the question into "answers to another situation". If you still feel your position is correct, feel free to roll it back ^^

Comment: @Kheldar Yes, that´s ok and I think so too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you´re only changing the values in the array, you don´t need to do anything special. Remove all `*` within the function and access the array like you don´t want to "return" it.

```
void swapRows(int row_1, int row_2, double **matrix, int n, int m){
    double arrTemp = (double *)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
    int i;  
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        arrTemp[i] = matrix[row_1][i];
        matrix[row_1][i] = matrix[row_2][i]; //no *
    }
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        matrix[row_2][i] = arrTemp[i]; //no *
    }
}
```

Unrelated problem, you´re missing a free to this malloc here.
And, as WhozCraig pointed out, in a `double **matrix` where each row is allocated separately, you could just switch the row pointers.

```
void swapRows(int row_1, int row_2, double **matrix, int n, int m){
    double *tmp = matrix[row_1];
    matrix[row_1] = matrix[row_2];
    matrix[row_2] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: The speed difference between the former and the latter cannot be overstated. Further, even the former can be done with no allocations, a single temporary `double` and one loop, though I cannot imagine why anyone would do so when the latter is O(1) vs O(n).